# Why does my digital clock function leak memory?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, memory-leaks

I have a digital clock function that takes the hours, minutes, and seconds from a JSON result, parses them as integers, does math on them (add 1 to the seconds every time it's looped through, if the seconds is 0, add 1 to minutes, etc.). After that math I parse these three variables as strings so I can then pad them with leading 0's for a result that looks like

10:05:34
(hours, minutes, seconds).

I use this method rather than datetimes because JS will always parse datetimes in local time, but the three variables are based on server time.

```
function countTime(){
        timeSeconds = parseInt(timeSeconds);
        timeMinutes = parseInt(timeMinutes);
        timeHours = parseInt(timeHours);

        timeSeconds = (timeSeconds + 1);
        if (timeSeconds == 60){timeMinutes = (timeMinutes + 1); timeSeconds = 0;};
        if (timeMinutes == 60){timeHours = (timeHours + 1); timeMinutes = 0;};

        //convert from 24 to 12 hour time, and "0" hour to 12
        if (timeHours > 12){
            timeHours = (timeHours - 12)
        };
        if (timeHours == 0){
            timeHours = 12;
        };

        //back to strings so that 0s can be padded
        timeSeconds = timeSeconds.toString();
        timeMinutes = timeMinutes.toString();
        timeHours = timeHours.toString();

        //pad 0s
        if (timeSeconds <= 10 && timeSeconds.length < 2)(timeSeconds = ("0" + timeSeconds));
        if (timeMinutes <= 10 && timeMinutes.length < 2)(timeMinutes = ("0" + timeMinutes));
        if (timeHours <= 10 && timeHours.length < 2)(timeHours = ("0" + timeHours));

        //show time
        timetext = timeHours + ":" + timeMinutes + ":" + timeSeconds
        $('#BT').html(timetext);
    };
```

Which is called by this function that sets it at an interval:

```
function updateTime() {
    countTime();
    timeInt = setInterval(countTime,1000);
    console.log('updated time from server');
};
```

`timeInt` is initialized globally before so I can clear that interval on a window focus event.
When I take this function out of my page, I have a memory use of around ~20kb that stays fairly certain. With this function included, memory use starts around 40kb and increases every second (which I think indicates a memory leak. . .). `updateTime` is called on a nonstandard interval (around every 45 minutes by the success callback of the AJAX call that gets `timeHours`,`timeMinutes`, and `timeSeconds`. Do I have a scope problem? Am I redifining variables needlessly when I have `countTime` on an interval?

Comment: You only need to call setInterval() once to initiate your clock.  If you call it multiple times then you'll have multiple timers running. Alternatively, you can use setTimeout which runs once and stops. Memory leaks are usually caused by [circular references](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-memleak).  Chrome has a [object allocation tracker](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling#object_allocation_tracker) which would help in identifying the problem ... if there is one.

Comment: i am also experiencing this problem.
every second the js heap goes up and after some minutes, it drops down. but it doesnt drop down to the starting value, but a little above that so we get a kind of a regression curve which is slowly increasing...

Answer (score 1):

You are leaking the interval timers. You need to call `clearInterval` before initializing it again.

```
function updateTime() {
    countTime();
    clearInterval(timeInt); // Here
    timeInt = setInterval(countTime,1000);
    console.log('updated time from server');
};
```

Comment: OP says that updateTime() is only called every 45 minutes, yet memory usage is increasing on a much shorter timescale.